# RequireJS components sometimes not loading

Tags: magento-2.1, performance, requirejs

We are launching a Magento 2.1.3 site, and finding that the site will sometimes load all of its Javascript components and dependencies properly, but sometimes fails to load, in which case a slider is not displayed and the console log shows error messages such as "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).swMegamenu is not a function".

How would we go about troubleshooting and resolving the source of these issues?

Comment: hope fully their might be a JQuery conflict.Try to short out the conflict.

Comment: Please post your js code.

Comment: The relevant code causing the error I included is: `<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu'
    ], function ($) {
        $(".sw-megamenu").swMegamenu();
    });
</script>`

Comment: We're observing today that the site will load the components on a normal reload, but not on a hard reload.

Comment: Also, the problems seem to only occur in Magento production mode, not developer mode.

Comment: We arrived at a working solution by adjusting Magento settings. The instruction we received from Smartwave support was to enable merge javascript files in `Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > JavaScript Settings.>`

Comment: @GordonKrauthamer I also having the same problem, Javascript is not loading sometimes. Did you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope fully their might be a JQuery conflict.Try to short out the

You can assign a variable.You should add the below line of code where `swMegamenu` located in.

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and use the variable **jq** instead of **$** like `jq(...).swMegamenu`

Hope fully this might help you.